# iOS app performs much better natively than through Xcode run

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm building a video application, and I noticed it performs much better when it I simply run it natively through my iPhone versus building and running it through XCode to my iPhone.

Why is this? Is there some sort of instrumentation overhead?

Comment: It has a debugger running while connected to Xcode.

Comment: Do you know if the debugger takes up a significant amount of the iPhone's CPU?